# Когда написал программу на python 2.7, все работало, перешел на 3.7, прога не работает, но почему?

Tags: python, алгоритм

> Уровень A.
>   Напишите программу, которая вычисляет сумму трех чисел, введенную в форме символьной строки. Все числа целые.

```
example = input('Введите пример: ')
example = list(example)
for i in range (len(example)):
    example[i] = int(example[i])
print (example)
```

Comment: @PythonLoveMe Попробуйте изменить последовательность написания программы. Сначала напишите ее на Python 3.7, а лишь затем на Python 2.7.:)

Comment: Имейте ввиду на будущее - Python 2 и Python 3 не имеют обратной совместимости. И в общем случае программа написанная на Python 2 не будет работать на Python 3 и наоборот

Comment: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '25+30' Вот такую ошибку python выдает

Comment: input в третьем питоне не считает выражения и выдаёт просто строку "25+30" как есть

Comment: Я пытаюсь использовать функцию list(), а после, с помощью цикла конвертирую каждый строковый элемент в int(), но он все равно выдает ошибку из-за '+' это происходит

Comment: В коде, который вы привели, нет никакой функции ``list()``. Гадать, как именно вы используете какую-то функцию, тут не любят. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив весь нужный код.

Comment: @Эникейщик «вы думаете, что можно написать во ввод "25+30" и получить результат?» — во втором питоне input именно так и работал

Comment: @andreymal Ай, блин, точно. Я автоматически заменил на raw_input и конечно же ничего не получилось :)

Comment: @PythonLoveMe, в py3 `input` возвращает то, что ввели, а чтобы было поведение как в `py2` нужно в `eval` поместить результат: `example = eval(input('Введите пример: '))`, но eval для вашей задачи нафиг не сдался :)

Comment: Почему, нормально вписался

Answer (score 1):

А зачем так усложнять-то? Всё просто.

```
example = input('Введите пример: ')    #25+45+30
print(eval(example))                   #100
```

Если подправить Ваш пример, то вот:

```
example = input('Введите пример: ')
example = example.split('+')

s = 0
for i in range(len(example)):
    s += int(example[i])
print(s)
```

Но он не будет учитывать отрицательные числа. Для этого нужно дополнительные проверки делать.